# Full outer join in PostgreSQL, create a new row if values are different and both are not null

Tags: postgresql, full-outer-join

My code can get me the result of example 1, but i really need to get example 2. I need to add another row if the two sourcecodes are both not null and different. Here's my code,please help:

[image]

```
select
cast(coalesce( y.masterentityid, u.masterentityid ) AS VARCHAR) AS MasterEntityId,
cast(coalesce( y.effectiveDate, u.effectiveDate ) AS TIMESTAMP) AS EffectiveDate,
....
....
....
cast(case when u.sourcecode = y.sourcecode then y.sourcecode when u.sourcecode is null or y.sourcecode is null then coalesce(u.sourcecode, y.sourcecode)
     else CONCAT(y.sourcecode,chr(10),u.sourcecode) end as VARCHAR ) AS sourcecode, 

cast(case when u.masterentityid = y.masterentityid then y.masterentityid when u.masterentityid is null or y.masterentityid is null then coalesce(u.masterentityid, y.masterentityid)
     when y.masterentityid is not null and u.masterentityid is not null then y.masterentityid
     when y.masterentityid is not null and u.masterentityid is not null then u.masterentityid end as VARCHAR) as masterentityid_2,

cast(case when y._RecordDate > u._RecordDate or u._RecordDate is null then y._RecordDate else u._RecordDate end as Timestamp) as LastChange
from Analytics_ConformYield_latest y
full outer join
ConformUnsubYield_latest u
on y.effectivedate = u.effectivedate
and y.masterentityid = u.masterentityid
```

I am thinking change the code to:

```
cast(case when u.sourcecode = y.sourcecode then y.sourcecode when u.sourcecode is null or y.sourcecode is null then coalesce(u.sourcecode, y.sourcecode)
     when y.sourcecode is not null and u.sourcecode is not null then y.sourcecode
     when y.sourcecode is not null and u.sourcecode is not null then u.sourcecode end as VARCHAR) as masterentityid_2,
```

Comment: Please show us the results that you expect, as tabular text;

Comment: Hi! The expected results is Example 2 above. My code can get me example1.

Comment: not sure if distinct will work? Basically I need the distinct not null sourcecode.

Comment: OK, so please show the sample data from both tables, as tabular text. Just the actual and expected results is not enough to guess what the correct query should be.

Comment: Hi GMB, let's say i have table A and B and want to get C. Please see a brief example as reference.A 
ID SOURCECODE
1 null
2 null
3 other      B 
ID SOURCECODE
2 BNY
3 BNY
4 BNY
 C 
ID Sourcecode 
1 null 
2 BNY 
3 other 
3 BNY 
4 BNY

Comment: I used Union to include both records...